# NG Live Development Server vs Traditional web server

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, command-line-interface

I am new to Angular2. I have stated learning through resources in Internet.

I am using Angular-Cli tools for building my test application.

When I issue command `ng serve --open` I got my example project running on a default port 4200 and console shows,

```
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
```

Now I am very confused with **NG Live Development Server**.

I have the following concerns,

- Being a Client Side Framework why angular needs an development server.
- Where Live Server is physically Located in running machine
- The Live Server
  can serve only Javascript or any other language.
- What is the
  complexity in integrating Angular2 application with Server side
  frameworks like Spring-MVC.

Could anyone please provide your thoughts on this? Please correct me if I have understood the concepts wrongly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tl;Dr the cli live server is only for local development. Not for production or any environment other than local dev.

To answer your specific questions:

> Being a Client Side Framework why angular needs an development server.

Angular is an SPA framework. The compiled application code needs to be loaded into the browser from a web server.

> Where Live Server is physically Located in running machine

The server is part of Webpack, which is a dependency of Angular-CLI. So it is in your node_modules folder.

> The Live Server can serve only Javascript or any other language.

The development server is only for running your Angular code on your local development machine. If you have a API backend, you should look at [proxying](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) requests through the dev server to your dev API.

> What is the complexity in integrating Angular2 application with Server side frameworks like Spring-MVC.

This is trivial. You will not host your Angular application in production on the live dev server. Instead you will run `ng build --prod --aot` to build the production bundles into the project `dist` folder. These are the build artefacts that will be deployed to your frontend webserver. Configure the frontend to run at the root contest i.e. `www.foo.com/` and the the Spring API to run at the /api context `www.foo.com/api/`.

Comment: Very useful..Thanks

Comment: Thanks - the link you provided for 'proxying' is the answer I've been looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to take a look at this:

[Node live server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server)

This clearly explains what exactly is a live server and also how it works:
Quoted from the link:

> The server is a simple node app that serves the working directory and
>   its subdirectories. It also watches the files for changes and when
>   that happens, it sends a message through a web socket connection to
>   the browser instructing it to reload. In order for the client side to
>   support this, the server injects a small piece of JavaScript code to
>   each requested html file. This script establishes the web socket
>   connection and listens to the reload requests. CSS files can be
>   refreshed without a full page reload by finding the referenced
>   stylesheets from the DOM and tricking the browser to fetch and parse
>   them again.

If you go through the entire post, you would get the answer to almost all your questions.